# How to delete columns excel file?

Tags: excel, matlab

I have installed Matlab r2010a on my computer

I need to get the data from a XLSX named `myExample` then verify if was processed before (it has to have certain number of columns). if was processed then do nothing. but if was not processed is required to delete the hearder row and several columns (**overwrite the existing file**).

Thanks a lot.

### example code

```
fname = 'myExample.xlsx'
values = {1, 2, 3, 4 ; 5, 6, 7, 8 ; 9, 10, 11, 12};
headers = {'First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth'};
xlswrite(fname, [headers; values]);
```

### myExample.xlsx contains:

```
First    Second    Third    Fourth
   1         2        3         4
   5         6        7         8
   9        10       11        12
```

Now I ask what you want to change into the file (Delete headers and some columns).

```
ColsDelete = {'B', 'D'};
```

### Outcome

After run the matlab script a verify if was prcessed or not and deleted the first row and column B and D. Now `myExample.xlsx` contains:

```
1    3
5    7
9   11
```

This way is nice because you just put the columns you do not need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of deleting columns, would it not be more advisable to create a new xlsx file that contains just the data you need? I only suggest this because I too process many xls files and if I make a mistake in coding, i might lose data I didn't mean to delete (a simple off-by-one error might have you deleting all the columns you wanted to keep instead of the ones you wanted to throw away).

Use [`xlsread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/xlsread.html) to read from your original file `fname.xlsx` and then use [`xlswrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/xlswrite.html) to write just the data you want to keep into another file `fname_processed.xlsx`.